# is there any way i could do to be specific to my if else statements?

Tags: java, class, object

im a java newbie and can't seem to terminate my code wisely,here is my if else statement and what it does is just subtracts the other if statements,is there anyway i could do to subtract the availAmount to a specific if statement? thank you

```
double upgradeAccessories(double availAmount) 
{
    if(availAmount>21500)
    {
        hasAC=true;
        availAmount-=21500;
    }
    else 
    {
        hasAC=false;
    }
    
    if(availAmount>=14400) 
    {
        hasLeatherSeats=true;
    availAmount-=14400;
    }
    else
    {
        hasLeatherSeats=false;
    }
    
    if(availAmount>=6250) 
    {
        hasBackWipers=true;
    availAmount-=6250;
    }
    else 
    {
        hasBackWipers=false;
    }
    
    if(availAmount>=3300)
    {
        hasFogLights=true;
    availAmount-=3300;
    }
    else 
    {
        hasFogLights=false;
    }

    return availAmount;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying `can't seem to terminate my code wisely`. What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: the availAmounts' value is 25000 ,i want it to be Only AC Installed
Remaining Amount = (25000 - 21500) = 3500 like this but what i did was it just subtracts the other if statements.

Comment: if 25000 value is there , then all if statements are true. can you please rephrase what your exact requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want one if statement to run then you need to use the `if (...) { ...} else if` syntax. Changing your code so that the `availAmount` is only reduced once could be done with something like the following:

```
double upgradeAccessories(double availAmount) {
   
    hasAC = availAmount > 21500;
    hasLeatherSeats = availAmount >= 14400;
    hasBackWipers = availAmount >= 6250;
    hasFogLights = availAmount >= 3300;

    if(availAmount > 21500) {
        availAmount -= 21500;
    } else if(availAmount >= 14400) {
        availAmount -= 14400;
    } else if(availAmount >= 6250) {
        availAmount -= 6250;
    } else if (availAmount >= 3300) {
        availAmount -= 3300;
    }

    return availAmount;
}
```

Note that in the above I also directly used your conditions to set the 4 boolean variables at the very beginning of the method, so that this doesn't have to be done in the if..else block.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```java
double upgradeAccessories(double availAmount) {
    hasAC           = availAmount >  21500;
    hasLeatherSeats = availAmount >= 14400;
    hasBackWipers   = availAmount >= 6250;
    hasFogLights    = availAmount >= 3300;

    if (hasAC)           return availAmount - 21500;
    if (hasLeatherSeats) return availAmount - 14400;
    if (hasBackWipers)   return availAmount - 6250;
    if (hasFogLights)    return availAmount - 3300;

    return availAmount;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. Elegant.